# How to calculate totals across columns with muliple criteria?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add totals per grade level, of each program code. There are more than 26 program codes to total, and they are scattered over 6 columns. I need to total the program codes by school, by grade, like the output shows.

I'm sorry I have no code, but I don't even know where to start on this.

**DataSet:**

[image]

**Output desired:**

[image]

The totals on the output are grouped by school, by gradelevel.

Can SQL do this, if so, how please?

Thank you!

Comment: Is `Program Code 1` different than `Program Code 2`?  Like does it mean something different, or are they actually just repeating fields where the order doesn't mean anything?  If so, you're looking at `UNPIVOT()` and `PIVOT()`.

Comment: Each student gets 6 program codes depending on how they are served.  So, they are not repeating fields.  Each column can be one of about 30 different characters.

Comment: Then how are you differentiating the program code in the desired output if they're different?  Was your desired output just Program 1 then?  Also, is school code your building number, or is that your student ID?  In my SIS, school code would decidedly be the building!

Comment: I am not exactly sure where the output file came from.  I have to recreate it.  The school code is the schoolID and represents at building.  The studentID is unique to the student.  It's like I have to total by column, then add all 6 program code columns together, for each of the 30 or school program codes, grouped by school, and by grade.  I just am not getting my head around it yet.  Thanks @BaconBits

Comment: Then I see no way to arrive at the desired output from the dataset.  I assume the desired out put says "in grade 12 at building 111, 2048 students had program code D".  However, your original data set just says "at building 579 in grade 3, program code 1 was B".  There's no student ID in your data set, only building data.  Furthermore, you're saying that program code 1 is actually distinct from program code 2 and they're not repeating groups, but the desired output doesn't say if it's program code 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.  There is not enough information to produce the output from your data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you started

```
select 
school_code
,grade_level 
,sum(case when [program code 1] = 'A' 
            or [program code 2] = 'A' 
            or [program code 3] = 'A' 
            or [program code 4] = 'A' 
            or [program code 5] = 'A' 
            or [program code 6] = 'A' 
            then 1  else 0 end )as A
,sum(case when [program code 1] = 'B' 
            or [program code 2] = 'B' 
            or [program code 3] = 'B' 
            or [program code 4] = 'B' 
            or [program code 5] = 'B' 
            or [program code 6] = 'B' 
            then 1  else 0 end )as B
,sum(case when [program code 1] = 'C' 
            or [program code 2] = 'C' 
            or [program code 3] = 'C' 
            or [program code 4] = 'C' 
            or [program code 5] = 'C' 
            or [program code 6] = 'C' 
            then 1  else 0 end )as C

--... Repeat the above or however many program codes you have

from
    --Whatever table you need to use 


group by 
School_Code
,Grade_level
```

Comment: After I put a parenthesis after the word end, it worked!  Thanks @lookslikeanevo!

Comment: So when you sum using a case like this, it sums all columns listed together?  Thanks again!

Comment: @JM1 it will give you a sum of each code grouped by school code and grade level

Comment: added parenthesis in answer